# Why does julia throw an LoadError in addition to the error I want to throw

Tags: error-handling, julia

If I write a script that does nothing else than throwing an error like this:

```
throw(ErrorException("a useful message"))
```

I get the following error when I execute the script.

```sh
$ julia throwError.jl
ERROR: LoadError: a useful message
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /path/throwError.jl:1
 [2] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:380
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:368
 [4] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:296
 [5] _start() at ./client.jl:506
in expression starting at /path/throwError.jl:1
```

I'm wondering why there is a `LoadError:` in my error message.

I get the same with other error types. For example:

```
throw(DivideError())
```

```sh
$ julia throwError.jl
ERROR: LoadError: DivideError: integer division error
stacktrace:
  ...same as above...
```

Comment: Cross-post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-throws-additional-loaderror-during-exception-handling/56446

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full answer to the "Why?" In this question is fairly involved. One way to answer is to simply refer to the docstring for `LoadError`:

> ```
> LoadError(file::AbstractString, line::Int, error)
> ```
>
> An error occurred while [`include`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.include)ing, [`require`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.include)ing, or [`using`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#using) a file. The error specifics
> should be available in the `.error` field.

So because the error happened while julia was trying to include the file and not when a function in the file was called after successful inclusion the error is wrapped in a `LoadError`.

But does Julia really have to wrap errors in `LoadError`s? The answer seems to be no, as Julia's backtraces have improved, `LoadError`s are no longer necessary to ensure that the developer has the necessary information about the location of the error. Since before 1.2 a [PR that deprecates them has been pending](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/31882#issuecomment-488224367). There are still some things to be figured out it seems but we'll hopefully be rid of them soon.

Other relevant links:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/31881 : Merged PR: `Ensure syntax error locations appear in backtraces` - improvement of backtraces for the purpose of enabling removal of `LoadError`.

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31830#issuecomment-487453858 : Comment explaining some of the background for the deprecation `LoadError`.